# How to change data in Lightning Datatable based upon a dropdown select filter?

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a datatable of certain groups. There is a Field on group Object(Datatype: checkbox ) which makes a group global ( there are two types of groups -Global and Local), How can I make a filter in Lightning datatable such that whever I select Global/Local from Dropdown (lightning:select) the data in table should Change.

Examples would be much appreciated!!

Lightning Component:-

```
<aura:component controller="PDCNGroupListController" 
implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable" 
                access="global" >
    <!-- New PDCNGroup Object -->
    <aura:attribute name="PDCNGroup" type="PDCNGroup__c"
                    default="{
                             'SObjectType': 'PDCNGroup__c',
                             'Name': '',
                             'Description__c': '',
                             }">            
    </aura:attribute>
    <aura:attribute name="isLoading" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isLoading}">
        <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="medium" aura:id="isLoading"/>
    </aura:if>
    <lightning:card title="PDCN Groups">
        <!-- Body of lightning card starts here -->
        <aura:set attribute="actions">
            <!-- New button -->
            <lightning:button label="New" 
                              variant="brand"
                              onclick="{!c.newPDCNGroup}" />
        </aura:set>
    </lightning:card>
    <div class="slds-m-left_small">
        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" 
                             columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                             keyField="Id"
                             onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Controller.js:-

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        var actions = [{ label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' }];

        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: actions } },
            {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Description', fieldName: 'Description__c', type: 'text'}
        ]);
        helper.getData(component);
    },

    handleRowAction : function(component, event, helper){
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var row = event.getParam('row');
        // navigate to sObject detail page     
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": row.Id,
            "slideDevName": "detail"
        });
        navEvt.fire();
    },
    // Function used to create a new PDCNGroup
    newPDCNGroup: function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.newPDCNGrouphelper(component, event, helper);
    },

})
```

Helper.js

```
({
    getData:function(cmp){
        var action=cmp.get('c.getPDCNGroupList');
        action.setCallback(this,$A.getCallback(function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state==="SUCCESS"){
                var oResponse=response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set("v.mydata",oResponse);
            }else if(state==="ERROR"){
                var errors=response.getError();console.error(errors);
            }
        }
        ));
        $A.enqueueAction(action)
    },

    newPDCNGrouphelper: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Global event force:createRecord is used
        var createPDCNGroup = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        // Parameters like apiName and defaultValues are set
        createPDCNGroup.setParams({
            "entityApiName": "PDCNGroup__c",
        });
        // Event fired and new contact dialog open
        createPDCNGroup.fire();
    },
})
```

Server Side Controller:-

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List <PDCNGroup__c> getPDCNGroupList() {
        return [SELECT Id, name, Description__c FROM PDCNGroup__c ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 200];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change data for datatable on on change of the lightning:select

```
<lightning:select aura:id="select" name="select" label="Select group" onchange="{! c.onChange }">
    <option value="">choose one...</option>
    <option value="apple">Global</option>
    <option value="pumpkin">Local</option>
</lightning:select>
```

On Change event:

```
({
onChange: function (cmp, evt, helper) {

    var action = cmp.get("c.getGroups");
    action.setParams({
        groupType: cmp.find('select').get('v.value')
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS" ) {
            var resultData = response.getReturnValue();
            cmp.set("v.data", resultData);
        }
    });
}
})
```

v.data is data attribute for datatable

```
<aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <lightning:datatable
            keyField="id"
            data="{! v.data }"
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

Apex Controller

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<GroupDataWrapper> getGroups(String groupType){
return wrappeddatafromsoql(or not wrapped if you have fields from group matching fieldnames of columns)
}
```

Comment: Can You Tell me using the code I added??

Comment: I basically provided you whole solution. Could you try to implement it? There isn't anything in your code that shows that you actually tried to do it

Comment: Yes I got your Point, But Thing is I don't Understand how table would be refreshed also Is there any thing in lightning components about filtering, I just want to get Concept. Thanks!!

Comment: When data for the table is changed (so the data attribute in comoponent) data table will refresh automatically. About filtering: for the data table component the isnt any out of the box solution. There is sorting -  you can read about it in the documentation of this component